# What assumptions about the data are require for Multiple Correspondence Analysis?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics, correspondence-analysis

In multiple correspondence analysis, what assumptions about the data are necessary in order to find the principal coordinates for the rows and columns?